# How can I avoid index out of range error with enumerating, while comparing each element to its neighbour?

Tags: python, list

I have an array that I am looping over and I want to compare each element to the element next to it, and if it is larger say, then I want to do something with its index. It's clear to me that enumeration would help in this case; however I am running into an `'index out of range error'`:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

for index,i in enumerate(array): 
    if array[index]>array[index+1]: 
        ...
```

While I know there are other ways of doing this,
is there a way I can make the above work with `enumerate`? I tried to do enumerate(array)-1 ; knowing this would not work. But anything of this sort that would fix the indexing error? Thanks

I know we can easily do the above with simply using 'i' from the for loop, but just curious if I can manipulate enumeration here.

Comment: Your code uses items of `array` as indexes into `array`. This is a bad idea and *a part* of the problem.

Comment: I don't follow, what do you mean I am using items of array as indexes? The indexes are represented by 'i'?

Comment: If you want to keep it in a "one line" kind of fashion, you can `zip` the list with a `range` of it's length `zip( range( len( array ) ), array)`, otherwise you can just check that the larger index doesn't exceed the lenght.

Comment: @Patrick_Chong, in your code you should be using `index` in your array indexing, but you have written `i`: `if array[i]>array[i+1]:` -> `if array[index]>array[index+1]:`

Comment: Ohh I see! Okay let me change it

Comment: Yes, I see it now! Silly me...

Comment: `i` are items of the `array` but `index` is the index number into `array` where `i` is located.

Comment: Thanks for the spot Michael, I see the error in my code now

Comment: Since you don't want to loop through the last item, to avoid index out of range you could use: `for index,i in enumerate(array[:-1]): `

Answer (score 4):

You can just shorten the range:

```
for i, val in enumerate(array[:-1]): 
    if val > array[i+1]:
        # do stuff
```

If you don't need the index, you can use `zip` to the same effect:

```
for prev, crnt in zip(array, array[1:]):
    if prev > crnt:
        # do stuff not requiring index
```

The slicing requires `O(n)` extra space, if you don't want that, you can use your original approach without `enumerate`, but a simple `range`:

```
for i in range(len(array)-1): 
    if array[i] > array[i+1]:
        #  ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `zip` and slice:

```
for i, j in zip(array, array[1:]):
    print(f'i: {i} - j: {j}')
```

Output:

```
i: 1 - j: 2
i: 2 - j: 3
i: 3 - j: 4
```

Comment: You can omit one of the slices. `zip` is bound by the shorter iterable anyway.

Comment: It does cost extra space and time for a spurious slice. I'd say that's a bad habit ;-)

Answer (score 0):

What logic do you need to apply for the last element in the list?

You can use the range function instead of enumerate.

If you **don't** need to implement business logic to last element, then use below:

```py
array = [1,2,3,4]

l = len(array)

for i in range(l-1): 
    if array[i]>array[i+1]: 
        ...
```

If you **do** need to implement business logic to last element then use below:

```py
array = [1,2,3,4]

l = len(array)

for i in range(l): 
    if i==l-1:
        implemet last elemt logic
    else:
         if array[i]>array[i+1]:
         ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this way will set index at 0 and i at 1. A list is starting at 0 in Python. So at i=3, you are looking at array[i+1]=array[4] which does not exist ! That is why the program is saying 'index out of range error'.

Here is what I suggest if you want to stick with lists:

```
array = [1,2,3,4]

for i in range(len(array)-1): 
    if array[i]>array[i+1]: 
        ...
```

If you want to manipulate the index, then it will be the current index in your loop (i). Maybe I have not understood your issue correctly but I suggest you to use numpy if you want to work with array-like objects.

Charles